# How can i display results from a mysql query into Qradiobuttons in python

Tags: python, mysql, qt4, pyqt4, qradiobutton

Im doing a quiz for my coursework and im dont know how to display results of my msql query as a radio button. I know how to display my results within python traceback but nothing else. Im using pyqt and mysql to code but im dont know how to to display within a label and or a radio button. Heres the code which displays the results of the mysql query in python traceback.

```
def Showquestions(self):
    mycursor.execute("SELECT*FROM questiontable")
    mylist=mycursor.fetchall()
    for x in mylist:
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just put the query results inside a set of variables and use them in your radiobuttons ?

Besides SELECT * is bad practice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, would it be possible if you can do some basic code showing how can i do this as im unsure. the select query will change, and i just wanted to show i have tried this problem